# How would I create this text in a Discord.js Embed?

Tags: discord.js

I'm currently learning Discord.js, and I'm wondering how I would create the text below?

[image]

I tried a few ways that I know but none of those worked.

````js
const infoserver = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('')
  .setTitle(' **__INFO: MineCraft Server:__** ')
  .setDescription(
    '**Server IP:**```play.wizardcraftmc.com```\n**Supported Versions:** ',
  );
````

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include the code that you've tried with and what you got from those tries.

Comment: const infoserver = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('')
        .setTitle(' **__INFO: MineCraft Server:__** ')
        .setDescription('**Server IP:**```play.wizardcraftmc.com```\n**Supported Versions:** ')

This is what I tried and it doesnt do it

Comment: @StephenMaples This is an answer, so please don't post it as comment :)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/tmpfcG5x

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros It Uses the ``` and currently doesnt create what I was trying to. Im trying to figure out what is the correct symbols to use to create what I attached.

Comment: @StephenMaples No :D, I actually meant in the 'answer field' at the bottom of this page

Comment: @StephenMaples Do you want the server URL/IP to be on the same line? You could use a single backtick instead of three.

Comment: @Toasty I am sorry but I havent created an answer yet. Im still trying to figure out how to do it. Someone asked for the code that I had already so I posted it as a comment so they could see what I had

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros Let me try that

Comment: That worked @ZsoltMeszaros Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using a Single backtick does indeed work appreciate all the comments and help.

"@StephenMaples Do you want the server URL/IP to be on the same line? You could use a single backtick instead of three. – Zsolt Meszaros"